# Converting Qt pressure output to newtons

Tags: qt, tablet, pressure

I am working with an old Siemens tablet. What i am trying to do is to obtain the pressure exerted by the pen on the screen. I have managed to use a Qt software in C++ where `QTabletEvent::pressure()` returns pressure values of 0.0 to 1.0. My question is, how can i convert these values into newtons?
If the tablet has 256 pressure levels, what does that also mean in terms of newtons?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Qt Sensors: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsensors-index.html, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpressurereading.html

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabletevent.html#pressure):

> Returns the pressure for the device. 0.0 indicates that the stylus is
>   not on the tablet, 1.0 indicates the maximum amount of pressure for
>   the stylus.

For you it means that you can't get "absolute" value of pressure (at least via pure `Qt`), because it returns to you only relative info between 0 and 1, so your application can react accordingly to this info.

You can really use `QtSensors` or you can use native `API` of your hardware or you can try luck to get `maxPressure` from [Qt internals](http://cep.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.8.6-browser/d0/d45/struct_q_tablet_device_data.html#a77a59b100693cddef4b5403224b3342c) using int [`QTabletDeviceData::maxPressure`](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/src/gui/kernel/qapplication_p.h#L123), because `QTabletEvent::pressure()` get this info in next way:

```
qreal(pressure / qreal(tablet->maxPressure - tablet->minPressure))
```